# Runtime Overflow error in visual basic 6 code

Tags: vb6

Following code of Visual Basic 6.0 - SP2 is giving Overflow error. Can somebody explain why?

```
Private Sub Form_Click()

  Dim Qty as Long

  Qty= 290 * 113       '' 112 is working fine

  MsgBox Qty

End Sub
```

Comment: As a side note, you might want to consider [Service Pack 6](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5721).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type of an expression is determined by its members, not by the variable it is going to be stored in.

`113` gets typed as `Byte`.
`290` gets typed as `Integer` because it won't fit into a byte.

As the largest of the involved types is `Integer`, the entire expression `290 * 113` is typed as `Integer`. An `Integer` can contain at most `32767`, which is less than `290 * 113`.

It therefore overflows upon multiplication, before the result is stored into a `Long` variable.

Explicitly type at least one of the numbers as `Long`:

```
Qty = 290& * 113
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it, although I thought `!` was the long type indicator. Been a while since VB6 though :)

Comment: Thanks for quick response GSerg. I also found answer at http://vbcity.com/forums/t/42020.aspx. Anyway thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The `!` suffix is for `SINGLE` 32 bit floating point variables.

Comment: @MrSnrub Yep, had to look it up though. That's what 12 years of not using it does to your memory :)